Cppcheck : help for checking
When cppcheck only outputs
Checking src/distance.c ...

does it mean that it's not reporting any errors, or that the analysis is finished, or that it's in progress?
I looked on the internet, but there isn't a precise answer. And I had a look at the documentation, but it wasn't conclusive.

Yes, it means, cppcheck hasn't found any problems.

It does sound like it's in progress, so that's a good question.   I guess another problem is that it never gives any conclusion -- like "Finished check.  No problems found."   Is that right?

yes, that's it, I left it on for 10 minutes with no results at the end, but maybe I should wait longer?
